# Cross Browser Download .Bat Files

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, html

I am building a web tool that is meant to be used internally by the company I am currently working for. The tool needs to generate a bat file and run it on the user's computer from the browser. Creating the bat file works fine, the issue lies when trying to run the bat file. The bat files are on the network of the company, for the sake of the question lets say that

`batpath = \\domain\path\to\the\file.bat`

At first, I tried to use `window.open('file:' + batpath)` in JavaScript, which worked in Internet Explorer, but would only open a blank tab in Chrome. My work around to this was to display the folder where the bat file was and prompt the user to run their file there in Windows Explorer manually, but I was asked to make the whole process in the browser with now Windows Explorer.

The next thing I tried was to generate an anchor tag with the download attribute to download the bat file manually

The anchor tag would be `<a href="file://domain\path\to\the\file.bat" download>runbat</a>`

That also works fine in Internet Explorer, but does not do anything at all in chrome.

Is what I am trying to do even possible? If so, how would I get this to work?

Comment: You can't do that.

Comment: I would immediately stop using any browser that was allowed to run arbitrary batch files on my computer.

Comment: [Chrome filters downloads](https://cdn.ghacks.net/wp-content/uploads/2014/07/google-protect-from-dangerous-sites.jpg) -  but 
 [You may able to white-list your tool](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/3123708?hl=en)

Comment: @SLaks I thought so, so I would have to just tell them that there is no other way than to use Windows Explorer to run the bats?

Answer (score 0):

I would create a URL protocol on the machine and have it execute the bat file.

Check this link: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa767914.aspx

Basically it's work like so:

1. Create the protocol and call CMD.EXE and pass in the bat file path
2. Call the protocol by generating the links "batrunner:file-path-to-bat.bat"

This should work on all browsers. You'd want to be careful doing this though and possible build a custom application to call the bat file for security reasons.